# Galois automorphism and linear independence

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\zeta$ be a 5th root of unity and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. Define $$\Phi: K \to \mathbb{C}^2, a \mapsto (\phi_1(a), \phi_2(a))$$
where out of $\operatorname{Gal} (K|\mathbb{Q})=\{\phi_1, \phi_2, \overline{\phi_1}, \overline{\phi_2}\}$ we take two automorphisms $\phi_1, \phi_2$ (and hence $\phi_1 \ne \overline{\phi_2}$.

Now I would like to prove that $\Phi(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta])$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Obviously, this is equivalent to saying that $\Phi(\zeta^i)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ für $i=0,1,2,3$, since the $\zeta^i$ form a $\mathbb{Z}$-Basis for $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

In his book *Complex Multiplication*, Lang simply writes that the $4\times 4$-Matrix with $i$th column vector $$(\phi_1(\zeta^i), \phi_2(\zeta^i), \overline{\phi_1 (\zeta^i)}, \overline{\phi_2(\zeta^i)})$$ is non-singular, as "$\zeta^i$ is a Basis for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (granted) and the elements $\phi_i, \overline{\phi_i}$ give all embeddings from $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$" (granted).

However, I don't understand how these facts imply that the matrix has no $\mathbb{R}$-dependent columns? Can anyone explain that please? Thanks in advance!